# How to install jenkins in bitnami lamp stack using ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, bitnami

I have ubuntu 14.04 server and installed bitnami lamp stack. Now I want to install the jenkins in this server. Kindly suggested me the procedure for that.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

we don't provide modules to install Jenkins in top of LAMPStack but you can install Jenkins using the installers of the stack. You can download them using this link:

https://bitnami.com/stack/jenkins/installer

This installer will install all the dependencies to run Jenkins. For example, it will install Apache and if you have another Apache running in the same port it will ask you to use another port.

I hope it helps.

Jota